# Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли делаю?

Tags: javascript, функции

Напишите функцию perimeterOfTriangle, которая принимает три аргумента a, b, c (стороны треугольника) и возвращает периметр треугольника, если треугольник существует, или сообщение 'The triangle does not exist', в противном случае.
Треугольник существует, если каждая из его сторон меньше суммы двух других сторон:

```
a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b
Примеры : 
функция perimeterOfTriangle(4, 5, 6); должна возвратить 15
console.log(perimeterOfTriangle(3, 2, 10); должна возвратить сообщение 'The triangle does not exist'.

function perimeterOfTriangle(a, b, c){
return (a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b) ? a + b + c : 'The triangle does not exist';
console.log(perimeterOfTriangle(4, 5, 6));
console.log(perimeterOfTriangle(3, 2, 10));
```

Comment: Похоже на правду. Только не хватает закрывающей фигурной скобки в конце функции `perimeterOfTriangle`. А вы таки почему спрашиваете? Код не проходит тесты?

Comment: Да прохожу тесты. Точно, а вот фигурную скобку по ошибке удалил. Спасибо !